# Scala Play framework json serializer for generic type

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework

If I have a trait such as:

```
trait MyTrait[T] {
    def myVal: T
}
```

And then I have a case class such as:

```
case class MyClass(val foo: Int, val myVal: Boolean) extends MyTrait[Boolean]
```

Finally, I have another case class

```
case class MyOtherClass(val bar: MyTrait[_])
```

How can I serialize and deserialize this last class to Json?

I made the reads and writes for myClass as follows:

```
object MyClass {
    implicit def MyClassWrites(implicit fmt: MyClass): Writes[MyClass] = new Writes[MyClass] {
        override def writes(m: MyClass) = Json.obj(
            "foo" -> m.foo,
            "myVal" -> m.myVal // myVal should be Boolean
        )
     }

    implicit def MyClassReads(implicit fmt: Reads[MyClass]): Reads[MyClass] = new Reads[MyClass] {
        override def reads(json: JsValue): MyClass = new MyClass(
            (json \ "foo").as[Int],
            true
        )
    }
}
```

myOtherClass also has a reads and writes, as follows:

```
object MyOtherClass {
    implicit def MyOtherClassWrites(implicit fmt: MyOtherClass): Writes[MyOtherClass] = new Writes[MyOtherClass] {
        override def writes(m: MyOtherClass) = Json.obj(
            "bar" -> Json.toJson(m.bar)
        )
    }
    implicit def MyOtherClassReads(implicit fmt: Reads[MyOtherClass]): Reads[MyOtherClass] = new Reads[MyOtherClass] {
        override def reads(json: JsValue): MyClass = new MyOtherClass(
            (json \ "bar").as[MyClass[Boolean]]
        )
    }
}
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
 Error:(43, 28) No Json serializer found for type A$A135.this.MyTrait[_$1]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
    "bar" -> Json.toJson(m.bar)
             ^
```

If I add a Writes to the trait as following:

```
object MyTrait {
    implicit def MyClassWrites(implicit fmt: MyTrait[_]): Writes[MyTrait[_]] = new Writes[MyTrait[_]] {
      override def writes(m: MyTrait[_]) = Json.obj(
          "myVal" -> Json.toJson(m.myVal) // myVal should be Boolean
      )
    }

    implicit def MyClassReads(implicit fmt: Reads[MyTrait[_]]): Reads[MyTrait[_]] = new Reads[MyTrait[_]] {
        override def reads(json: JsValue): MyTrait[_] = new MyClass(2, false)
    }
}
```

I now get this error:

```
Error:(10, 30) No Json serializer found for type _$4. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
    "myVal" -> Json.toJson(m.myVal) // myVal should be Boolean
               ^
```

I'm lost here, isn't there a way to serialize bar as if it is a MyClass?

I'vr also tried to change the writer for MyTrait as following:

```
override def writes(m: MyTrait[_]) = {
    m match {
        case c: MyClass => Json.toJson(c)
    }
}
```

Now the writer for the trait compiles but we get back to the first error:

```
Error:(45, 28) No Json serializer found for type A$A199.this.MyTrait[_$9]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
    "bar" -> Json.toJson(m.bar)
             ^
```

I don't get it, I have defined the writers and readers, haven't I?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to defines the following instances.

```
implicit def MyTRead[T](implicit r: Reads[T]): Reads[MyTrait[T]] = ???
implicit def MyTWrite[T](implicit r: Writes[T]): Writes[MyTrait[T]] = ???
```

Comment: That didn't do it. I deleted my read and writes for the trait and used this instead, but the compiler still doesn't want to use it as the serializer for MyTrait. Maybe I'm not using it right though.